# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred: 504

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I get the following error message soon after 120 seconds. Report query returns the full data set in SSMS withing 25 seconds.

"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 504"

This is a fairly a large report. I get this same error messages with many of my large data reports.

Report server version 11.0.5058.0 on a VMware 2 GHz 4 core, 64GB RAM and Windows 2012 R2 (64 bit)

DB Server version Standard Edition (64-bit) 11.0.5058.0 on a VMware 2 GHz 8 core, 96GB RAM and Windows 2012 R2 (64 bit)

I've changed the following value in "rsreportserver.config" to 600. It was 120 befor. Still I get the same error message.

```
<Configuration>
    <Add Key="DatabaseQueryTimeout" Value="600"/>
</Configuration>
```

I do not use a separate IIS in my setup. I use the SSRS built in webserver.

here is my post to msdn forum. It has the error message screen.
[msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb262fcc-f9e1-4fbe-b11c-65de6b11b2a8/syswebformspagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-an-unknown-error-occurred-while-processing-the?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
It is because of the local network proxy.
504 timeout is from proxy.
So if any of you came across this same issue, please try by passing the proxy and see.

Hope this post will help someone out there.

Regards,
-Jinantha

Comment: Hi.. can you please tell me how you do this? I've hit the same issue

Comment: Telling us that you figured it out, without telling us how you did it is not useful

Comment: I mentioned in my post to by pass your local network proxy. That's the solution. If you do not know how to by pass the proxy, then say that. for long running queries in your ssrs reports, the local proxy server will timeout waiting for a result from ssrs server to client, hence the error. you can ask your local network admin for a way to bypass the proxy.